# How do I make this into one big while statement?

Tags: matlab

I have an assignment that asks you to input a number between 1 and 25, do the factoral of a number, and then ask if you are done, if not, it restarts the loop and you do a new factoral.

I've been working on the code for it, and I made it work, up until the last step. I made a while loop for the numbers between 1 and 25, but a for loop for the factoral. When I tried to combine the two, It didn't work and spit out an error.

```
clear;
clc;
alldone = 'n';
fact = 1;
num = input('Input a number between 1 and 25: ');
    while (num < 1)||(num > 25);
       num = input('\n That is not between 1 and 25, please try again: ');
    for i=num:-1:2;
    fact = fact * i;
    fprintf('The factoral of %g is %g',num,fact);
    end
    alldone = input('Are you done? Type Y for yes: ', 's')
end
```

This is what I did, and I don't know how to turn the for loop into a while?
Does anyone know? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most efficient way to solve the problem, but I tried to keep as close as possible to your code.

```
clear;
clc;
alldone = 'n';

while alldone ~= 'Y'
    fact = 1;
    num = input('Input a number between 1 and 25: ');

    while (num < 1)||(num > 25);
        num = input('\n That is not between 1 and 25, please try again: ');
    end

    for i=num:-1:2;
        fact = fact * i;
    end

    fprintf('The factoral of %g is %g. \n', num, fact);
    alldone = input('Are you done? Type Y for yes: ', 's');
end
```

Since this is some sort of homework I will not explain what my little edits to your code do, leaving it as an exercise for you :) Of course you may ask, should you find it unclear. Good luck!

A bit of a suggestion: use proper indentation!

*A little addition in order to answer the OP*: the format of the output can be controlled using [formatting operators](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0hr54) and [conversion characters](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z8vc-1).

Comment: My only comment is that when I try out the code, I get 1.124e+21 as the factoral, is that because its using %g? Should I instead use %d? EDIT: I DID THAT THANK YOU! GOT IT!

Comment: glad you sorted it out, I updated the answer anyway :) congratulations!

Comment: @user2237848 In case you don't know: the factorial of `num` can be computed directly as `factorial(num)` or `gamma(num+1)`